# Best tool in unix for viewing large files

Tags: bash, unix, shell, vi, ksh

I am a novice in unix.
I am facing a problem in viewing big log files in unix using `vi`.
Could you please suggest the best tool for fast viewing of big files on unix?
Additionally, could you to post your own ways of viewing the big files on unix?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`less` doesn't need to keep the whole file in memory so it is good for viewing giant files. But for log files, the line wrapping is a nuisance.

Comment: Which you can disable with "-S" ;)

Comment: +1 for less. And for viewing log files that keep changing, you can press shift-f, which will emulate a 'tail -f' on the file. And as a bonus, if you had highlighted something with a search, the new incoming text will also be highlighted.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you are looking for in this big log file.

- If you just want to be impressed by its size, `cat` is enough (you can also roughly locate some unexpected visual patterns).
- If you just want to take a look at it, you can use `more` or `less`.
- If you want to monitor it while it is growing, you may be interested by `tail -f`.
- If you are looking for specific patterns, take a look at `grep`.
- If you want to extract some useful information from your big data, `perl` or `python` are your friends.

Comment: I prefer `less <filename>` then Shift-F to follow, personally, over `tail -f` :)

Answer (score 5):

Actually `vi` (at least `vim`) is very performant on large files. I regularly use it to edit files in the dozens of MB range without problems.

You just need to be aware that a few operations will be slow on large files: big visual selects, global searching, and syntax highlighting. For large files, always turn off syntax highlighting (if you have it on by default): :syn off . Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `less` as they have already told you, or `most` which is an extended version of `less` with more options and cool stuff.

It is usually included in the repository of any linux distro.

Comment: +1 for `most` and its multiple windows (although I mostly use `less`).

Comment: thanks :)
I don't understand why the negative vote, maybe someone tought I was pulling the leg :-)

Answer (score 0):

less and tail are the most efficient for viewing long files. less displayes a portion of file at a time and you need to scroll it in up direction whereas tail facilitates you to view the last n number of lines.